# Have 2 package.json file and want to merge into one, do I have to do it manually?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, node-modules, package.json

In the project there are two package.json files. How can I merge those two package.json files, one is in the root folder and the other is present in one of the subdirectories, into 1 file?

Comment: Is there an issue with doing it manually? At least with this method you can check at each stage what should be included. Note that sometimes projects do have more than one package.json (for example a monorepo that separates client/server code/dependancies) so be sure first that merging them is the right thing to do.

Comment: thanks @Andy, just wanted to confirm if after merging the package.json file present in the root folder will make the dependencies available to the subfolders and files right?

Comment: That's correct,